# Condition on $user_storage

Tags: 8, database

I am using the following code.

```
  $user_storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('user');

    $ids = $user_storage->getQuery()
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('roles', 'directeur_cr_')
      ->execute();
    $users = $user_storage->loadMultiple($ids);
```

I want to add a condition that is verified when the role is *directeur_cr_* or *comptable_cr_*.

How can I add this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [orConditionGroup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/function/QueryInterface%3A%3AorConditionGroup/8.6.x), but the IN operator is a shorthand for OR conditions on the same field:

```
->condition('roles', ['role1', 'role2'], 'IN')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
  $user_storage = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('user');

    $ids = $user_storage->getQuery()
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('roles', array('directeur_cr_','comptable_cr_'),'IN')
      ->execute();
    $users = $user_storage->loadMultiple($ids);
```